# Old contracts data not visible if pushed new contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethereumjs, infura, react

I created a contract campaign and deployed this contract in infura , then I called some functions of the contract which created the subsequent data(as in list of ongoing campaigns) in blockchain.
In these campaigns people can contribute some ether to these campaigns(this required  payable keyword). I was able to view these from my front end application created using react .

Now , I added some public view functions to the contract  , rebuilt and redeployed the same , when I tried accessing this , I was not able to view any of my old data (none of the old campaigns) ,

What might have happened to them?

And how can we persist data in these releases ?

I am new to blockchain , please help me in understanding the flow. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by referring to [How do Proxy Upgraded Logic Contracts Share Data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79918/how-do-proxy-upgraded-logic-contracts-share-data/79920#79920)

This suggests we have proxy contracts

Comment: "Old data" are still on the blockchain, when you deploy a newest version of a contract, the oldest one still persist on the blockchain (beacuse of the blockchain technology behavior, immutability!), so if you try and call the oldest address you used (whit also the oldest abi) you will get the previous data.
So if you plan to have an upgradable contract, a proxy contract and a state contract could be a good way, but remember that this involves higher gas cost (to read/write from the state contract, the proxy contract create a new transaction)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts from that link here.  Answers consisting only of links are not particularly helpful and are liable to be deleted.

Comment: Cool thanks  , Chenmunka as Dibi91 explained  , thats the same.